# App crashing during AdHoc but not during debug

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash

There is 1 class in my app that is crashing during AdHoc deployment but works fine if installed through Xcode. I've symbolicated the crash logs from my device (iOS 10) and they are all the same:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   UIKit                           0x0000000196507a4c __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 424
1   UIKit                           0x00000001965079f0 __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 332
2   UIKit                           0x00000001964c7368 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2712
3   UIKit                           0x00000001964c67e4 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 536
4   UIKit                           0x00000001964c6570 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
```

So my thought is, Ok maybe there is a problem with how I'm finding my section count. Here is the code for my class, it's pretty straight forward.

```html
class HeaderTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var nonDefaultTitle : String?
    
    var data: [String: [String]] = [:]
    
    var headers : [String]       = []
    var bodys   : [[String]]     = []
    
    
    init(displayData: [String: [String]]) {
        super.init(style: .Plain)
        data = displayData
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        for key in data.keys {
            headers.append(key)
        }
        
        for arr in data.values {
            bodys.append(arr)
        }
 
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DefaultCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCustomCell")
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100;
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "HeaderTableHeaderView", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderTableHeaderView")
        
        if let ttle = nonDefaultTitle {
            self.title = ttle
        }
        else {
            self.title = "Talking Tips"
        }
    }
}

//
// MARK: Helpers
//
extension HeaderTableViewController {
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return headers.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bodys[section].count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("HeaderTableHeaderView")
        let header = cell as? HeaderTableHeaderView
        header!.titleLabel.text = headers[section]

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DefaultCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DefaultCustomCell
        
        cell.titleLabel.text = bodys[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { }
}

//
// MARK: The table headers
//
class HeaderTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I mean it's realllly straight forward. Again, the app works fine if I install through xcode. Even if I install, kill the app, then reopen, all works fine.

Whenever I try to install over AdHoc (using Diawi) the stupid thing crashes in this class.

Comment: Strange that this is there: rectForFooterInSection, yet you're not doing anything with the footers. Perhaps try setting sectionFooterHeight to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being this. Setting this:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

In `viewDidLoad()` will not cause a crash when installed from xcode. When installed OTA it will. Normally I duplicate my "Release" build settings so I thought maybe something there was different. I created a new configuration duplicating "Debug" and the same crash happened. I don't know if this is a bug on Apple side or not.

Anyway, you don't need to set in `viewDidLoad()`, all you need to do is have this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```